# Users get pass simple If check

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a browser game where you can upgrade your `attack`,`defence`,`spies` and `patrol` by clicking on submit button. every upgrade cost X gold and X food.
this is the address to the game (it's in hebrew): 
http://www.mafia.co.il

In the last few days some users found a way to upgrade it without having enough gold/food. The result is that they have minus in that resource of the game. ofcourse I thought I blocked this option.

also, for some reason they are able to upgrade it more then 10 times - when you'll read the code you'll see that I at least try to block that option.

Please does someone have any idea where is the problem?

This is the upgrade code (I translate the hebrew parts to english, I also added notes):

the reason for the `foreach` loop is to get the name of the `$_POST`.

```
elseif (isset($_POST['attack']) || isset($_POST['defence']) || isset($_POST['spies']) || isset($_POST['patrols']))  {
    // Get user details
    $ud = details($user_id);
    foreach($_POST as $name => $val)    {
    // Number came with ','. So here i'm removing it.
        $pr['gold'] = str_replace(',','',get_upg_price($ud['cvl'][$name]));
        $pr['food'] = str_replace(',','',get_upg_price($ud['cvl'][$name]));
         // Check if the user has enough food and gold.
        if (check_rsc($pr,$ud)) {
        // Check if user has maximum upgrade possible.
            if ($ud['cvl'][$name] < 10) {
                mysql_query("UPDATE `civ_level` SET ".$name."=".$name."+1 WHERE ID='".$user_id."'");
                mysql_query("UPDATE `resources` SET gold=gold-'".$pr['gold']."', food=food-'".$pr['food']."' WHERE ID='".$user_id."'");
                update_power($user_id);
            }   else    {
                $error = "<tr><td colspan='8' style='color:black; background: #CC3333; border:1px solid white;'>you are at maximum possible upgrade.</td></tr>";
            }
        }   else    {
            $error = "<tr><td colspan='8' style='color:black; background: #CC3333; border:1px solid white;'>You dont have enough resources.</td></tr>";
        }
    }
}
```

Function details:

```
function details($id)   {
    $select1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE ID='".$id."'");
    $sel = mysql_fetch_array($select1);
    $array['usr'] =  $sel;
    $select2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user_d` WHERE ID='".$id."'");
    $sel2 = mysql_fetch_array($select2);
    $array['usd'] =  $sel2;
    $select3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `resources` WHERE ID='".$id."'");
    $sel3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($select3);
    $array['rsc'] =  $sel3;
    $select4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `train_price`");
    $sel4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($select4);
    $array['trp'] =  $sel4;
    $select5 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `civ_level` WHERE ID='".$id."'");
    $sel5 = mysql_fetch_array($select5);
    $array['cvl'] =  $sel5;
    if (empty($array['usd']))   {
        return false;
    }   else    {
        return $array;
    }
}
```

Function get_upg_price:

```
function get_upg_price($level)  {
    $a = 0;
    $price = 100;
    while ($a<$level)   {
        $price = $price*3;
        $a++;
    }
    return number_format($price);
}
```

Function check_rsc:

```
function check_rsc($array,$ud)  {
    foreach ($array as $name => $val)   {
        if ($ud['rsc'][$name] < $val)   {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Example of an input:

`<form method='post'><input type='submit' name='attack' value='train' />`

Thank you!

Comment: we don't have any idea what your database looks like, why don't you add in some of of the query results that would normally be run the the case of these bugs.

Comment: Did you check for SQL Injections? \e: Why do you output `number_format`ted price and remove the comma afterwards?

Comment: @RedAlert I didn't added it because the query never should run. there is an `IF` condition that check if the user have enough resources. Somehow some users was able to pass it and get their resources to minus. @Sbls I didn't check but I dont think that this is the case here, because all users who cheated was only able to upgrade their `attack,defence,spies and patrols` to a very high level which not soupose to be possible to get. If it was SQL injection I geuss they use it on other tables. In addition the update query doesn't have any user input...

Comment: @OfirH there are queries that your if condition depends on, and we have no idea how they will evaluate.

Comment: @RedAlert I guess you mean that query `$select5 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM civ_level WHERE ID='".$id."'");`. `civ_level` is containing this fields: `ID, attack,defence,spies,patrols` - all of them is `INT`. there is another table you need to know how it looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Always but always Use `addslashes($userInput)`,
The `addslashes` function will keep you safe from the sql injection and preventing you from users to cheat on the game.

Never let the variable go directly on the database
That is your error